# Can't get bitmap to upload to php server?

Tags: android, image, upload

I'm trying to get my app to upload an image taken with the camera to a server. I know it's not the server, because I can access the url perfectly fine with no issue. I'm getting `Error in http connection android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` as the error. Here is the code I'm trying to use.

```
public void uploadFile(Bitmap file) {
        Bitmap bitmapOrg = file;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);
        byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();
        String ba1=Base64.encodeBytes(ba);

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",ba1));

        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://example.info/appserver/upload.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
        } catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Network activity can't be done on the main thread (the UI thread) since it dramatically impacts how your application feels to users. Check out the [training doc on doing network access using AsyncTasks](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#AsyncTask) for a solution.